# Puppet,git: Unable to clone

Tags: puppet, centos7, git, clone

My puppet master has code as below

```
vcsrepo {'/var/www/html':
                ensure => 'present',
                provider => 'git',
                source => "https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki.git",
                revision => 'REL1_23',
                }
        file {'/var/www/html/index.html':
                ensure => 'absent',
        }


        FILE['/var/www/html/index.html'] -> Vcsrepo['/var/www/html']
```

And I am unable to do git commit while running puppet agent as below

```
puppet agent --debug --verbose --no-daemonize --onetime
```

And I am getting below error

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache/Apache::Vhost[default]/File[/var/www/html]/ensure: created
Debug: /Stage[main]/Apache/Apache::Vhost[default]/File[/var/www/html]: The container Apache::Vhost[default] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: /File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf]/seluser: Found seluser default 'system_u' for /etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf
Debug: /File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf]/selrole: Found selrole default 'object_r' for /etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf
Debug: /File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf]/seltype: Found seltype default 'httpd_config_t' for /etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf
Debug: /File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf]/selrange: Found selrange default 's0' for /etc/httpd/conf.d/15-default.conf
Debug: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/File[/var/www/html/index.html]: Nothing to manage: no ensure and the resource doesn't exist
Debug: Executing '/usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki.git /var/www/html'
Error: Execution of '/usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki.git /var/www/html' returned 128: Cloning into '/var/www/html'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Vcsrepo[/var/www/html]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki.git /var/www/html' returned 128: Cloning into '/var/www/html'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Strange thing is

```
/Stage[main]/Apache/Apache::Vhost[default]/File[/var/www/html]/ensure: created
```

and

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Vcsrepo[/var/www/html]/ensure: change from absent to present failed
```

Comment: Are you able to run `/usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki.git /var/www/html` from the server? Looks like you may have a firewall between you and GitHub.

Comment: I am able to execute same command via Ubuntu puppet agent from same network , facing issue only with CentOS Puppet agent.

Comment: Did you check to see if SELinux was disabled/permissive?

Comment: @AWippler yes SELinux was permissive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my CentOS agent in VirtualBox ,so I think my VM network is slowing down gradually while downloading large files.

So I have opened another tab and placed `ping google.com` and executed 
`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` in the terminal and then started checkout and it went fine.

Adding it as answer, hope it my helps someone who are running same environment as me.

Thank you.